# Which of the following values will position an element in relation to the nearest non-static element?

Tags: css

I am told that an absolute value will position an element in relation to the nearest non-static element.

But can't a relative element position itself in relation to another relative element?

I have to pick 1 answer to the main question, and the options are relative, absolute, static, fixed.

But I see that there are two answers to this question or am I wrong?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values

Answer (score 0):

Only "Absolute" value position element in relation to parent non-static element.

Answer (score 0):

An element with position "relative" is positioned relative to its normal(default static) position.

An element with position "fixed"  is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled.

An element with position "absolute" is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).